# Delete before a line with regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I use `preg_replace` in PHP to remove text before a substring as

```
unnecessary stuff
unnecessary stuff
DELETE ME and some more stuff
This line should be the beginning
the rest.
```

with

```
/^.{0,1000}DELETE ME/is
```

How can I delete the entire line of `DELETE ME` too?

I use `.{0,1000}` to limit the deletion.

Comment: Use: `/^.{0,1000}DELETE ME[^\n]*\n/is`

Comment: @anubhava wonderful! if you post an answer, I can accept it to complete the question.

Comment: Easier, use inline modifiers and account for the end of string: `/(?s)^.{0,1000}DELETE ME(?-s).*\R?/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to match:

```
/^.{0,1000}DELETE ME[^\r\n]*\R/is
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lDfSSG/1)

**Details:**

- `[^\r\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any character except `\r` and `\n`
- `\R`: Match any unicode end of line character

Comment: You solved the problem. Just a follow-up question. How can I limit the length of `DELETE ME` line. For example, match only if the line is less than 100 character. How can I include `{0,100} into the second part of the pattern?

Comment: You can use: `/^.{0,1000}DELETE ME[^\r\n]{0,99}\R/is`

Comment: silly me. I was trying to put `{0,100}` after `*`, and forgot that `{0,100}` does the job of `*` :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use inline modifiers to control what `.` matches:

```
'~(?s)^.{0,1000}DELETE ME(?-s).*\R?~i'
  ^^^^                   ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HwJ7LK/1)

The `(?s)` inline DOTALL modifier will make all `.` outside of character classes match any characters including all line break chars, and `(?-s)` will turn off this DOTALL mode, and all `.` to the right of it in the pattern will stop matching line break chars.

See [more details from rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall):

> **Inline Modifier `(?s)`**
>   In .NET, PCRE (C, PHP, R…), Perl, Python and Java (but not Ruby), you can use the inline modifier `(?s)`, for instance in `(?s)BEGIN .*? END`. See the section on [inline modifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers) for juicy details about three additional features (unavailable in Python): turning it on in mid-string, turning it off with `(?-s)`, or applying it only to the content of a non-capture group with `(?s:foo)`.

And [then](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers):

> ✽ Except in Ruby, `(?s)` activates "single-line mode", a.k.a. `DOTALL` modes, allowing the dot to match line break characters. In Ruby, the same function is served by `(?m)`

Also, using `\R?` you will also match at the end of the whole string if `DELETE ME` appears at the last line of the string as `\R?` matches 1 or 0 line breaks.